# Method "load" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render error on integrating @syncfusion/ej2-vue-maps package

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-3

Configuration:
System: Windows 10
Technology: Vuejs
Node Version: v10.14.1
Npm version: 6.4.1
**Description:**
Hello, I am using @syncfusion/ej2-vue-maps package to integrate below map in my vuejs project. 
[image: Maps · Marker · Syncfusion Vue UI Components]

I have added following lines of code in main.js file:

```
import { MapsPlugin, Marker, MapsTooltip, MapAjax } from '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-maps';
Vue.use(MapsPlugin);
```

After adding above line of code. I created an new file where I added the code to display maps with marker. Here is my Maps.vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
     <ejs-maps id='container' :load='load' :titleSettings='titleSettings' :zoomSettings='zoomSettings' :useGroupingSeparator='useGroupingSeparator' format='n'>
       <e-layers>
         <e-layer :shapeData='shapeData' :dataSource='dataSource' :shapeSettings='shapeSettings' :markerSettings='markerSettings'></e-layer>
        </e-layers>
      </ejs-maps>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Marker, MapsTooltip, MapAjax } from '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-maps';
import { topPopulation } from './map-data/marker-location.js';
import Template from './marker-temp.vue';

export default {
   data(){
      return{
         useGroupingSeparator: true, 
         zoomSettings: {
            enable: false
         },
         titleSettings: {
            text: 'Top 25 populated cities in the world',
            textStyle: {
               size: '16px'
            }
         },
         shapeData: new MapAjax('./map-data/world-map.js'),
         dataSource: topPopulation,
         shapeSettings: {
            fill: '#C3E6ED'
         },
         markerSettings: [
            {
               dataSource: topPopulation,
               visible: true,
               animationDuration: 0,
               shape: 'Circle',
               fill: 'white',
               width: 3,
               border: { width: 2, color: '#285255' },
               tooltipSettings: {
                  template: function () { return {template: Template}; },
                  visible: true,
                  valuePath: 'population',
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   provide: {
      maps: [Marker, MapsTooltip]
   }
}
</script>
```

On running the project I got below error: 
`Property or method "load" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`
What value we are getting in load ? Load is not defined in data also, So from where we are getting the load value? Also I have't found any file "marker-temp.vue" after installing library due to which it shows missing file error. Where is it? Please help. Is anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing load in your Data() so you must define load,

You are referencing something that doesn't exist. You must check the documentation of the component you are utilizing and see what kind of structure of load they expect you to give then define it.

```
data(){
  return{
    load: ""
  }
}
```

after looking through the documentation,I found this, check this [link](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/api/maps/#load)